# Lucene .NET fixed filenames in index directory possible?

Tags: static, lucene, indexing, lucene.net, filenames

When building a Lucene .NET index it creates several randomly named files under the root index directory. My question is, is there a way to have these files have a static or fixed name and just overwrite upon re-index, or all be in one file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [cfs](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_2/fileformats.html), there will be just one file (random stuff.cfs)